# Unable do access prop passed trough React Route/Link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built the following website using React and I am at a point where I need to request an API some data based on user search, so I tried passing the search text has a prop to the new component which will make the request and render the results, however, it complains about the prop that I pass being declared but never used. Ive started learning React about 2/3 weeks ago, so I'm pretty fresh here, have mercy :)

This class is the main one related to the Search part of the website:

```
class SearchPageContent extends React.Component{
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <a className="btn btn-primary" style={{ marginRight:"10px" }} href="/festivals/categorySearch" > Pesquisar por categoria </a>
            <a className="btn btn-primary" href="/festivals/textSearch"> Pesquisar por palavras-chave </a>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/festivals/categorySearch" component={CategorySearch}/>
                <Route exact path="/festivals/textSearch" component={TextSearch}/>
                <Route path="/festivals/textSearch/search=" component={SearchResults}/>
            </Switch>        
            <br/><br/>
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

This line:

```
<Route path="/festivals/textSearch/search=" component={SearchResults}/>
```

Is the Route of interest, which is supposed to take the text written and insert it in the url.
In this class is where I insert the `<Link>` tag:

```
class TextSearch extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        this.state = { textkeysearch : "" };
    }

    handleSearchText(e){
        this.setState({ textkeysearch : e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <div className="mt-3">
            <br/><br/>
            <input id="text-search" type="text" onChange={this.handleSearchText.bind(this)} />
            <Link to={{ pathname: "/festivals/textSearch/search=", state:{textInput : this.state.textkeysearch} }}>
                <a class ="btn btn-info ml-3" id="textSearch" href={"/festivals/textSearch/search=" + this.state.textkeysearch} >Procurar</a><br/>
            </Link>
            <span>*Insira uma palavra-chave - pode ser o nome do evento, o sítio onde irá decorrer, entre outros...</span>
            
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

And the component that is supposed to access the prop:

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        const textInput = this.props.match.params    <--------"textInput is declared but never used"
        //TODO axios()
    }
        
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>IARARARA</p>                       <--------This appears
                <p>{this.textInput}</p>               <--------This does not 
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I've been hitting my head for a couple times, tried a bunch of combinations, regarding `this` insertion before. Tried using a constructor instead, same result.

At some point i was sucessfull passing the written text through the url but ended with SearchPageContent and SearchResults mixed on the same page, and still couldn't access prop on the

tag.
Also tried `const {textInput} = this.props.match.params` instead, but the result is equal.

There a couple more things i tried which I do not remember, but always got the same result.

I'm also open to any sugestions that would improve my code.
I think the code i transcribed is suficient, but if not, I placed it in a remote repository if you want to check it: https://github.com/reborn12008/HitchHikers-Collab-React-

**UPDATE**

By creating a state in a constructor method like so:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state ={
        textWritten : this.props.location.state.textInput,
    }
}
```

And accessing in the same way : `{this.state.textWritten}`
Seems to work for rendering purposes.

Comment: you're not getting value of `this.props.match.params` in searchResults component this is the issue correct ???

Comment: `textInput` is a const within the scope of `componentDidMount`, it is not a class property. Referencing it with `this.textInput` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Brian Thompson Yes but i wrote that scope to make the request of the API, and thats the main thing i want to reach.

Comment: @pageNotfoUnd Yes that is the issue

Comment: you can declare `const textInput = this.props.match.params ` outside the componentDidMount and check

Comment: @pageNotfoUnd I believe the correct Syntax( as i can see it working in console.log()) is `const {textInput} = this.props.location.state`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
const paramsString = this.props.location.search;
const params = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
const foo = params.get('foo');
```

First of all you cannot access the variable in render method that is declared in any other function including componentDidMount, Second Render method will get called once before componentDidMount get called so you need validate that in your render method.

try rendering the params directly

```
render() {
  return (<p>{this.props.location.params}</p>) 
}
```

Or set the params in state in componentDidMount and render it from state.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    params: this.props.location.params
  })
}
```

And in your render method

```
render() {
  return (
   <div>{this.state.params && <p>{this.state.params}</p>}</div>
   ) 
}
```

Comment: I can't get it to work properly like that, but it with jut `const {textInput} = this.props.location.state` it catches the prop, but outside the componentDidMount, that const is unaccessible

Comment: I get `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {textInput}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` when rendering it directly or when i setState in componentDidMount() or even removing this function and just doing it in the constructor.

Comment: I manage to use state now without that error but now its says that `this.props.location.state` is equal to `[object Object]`